# Which one is used more by IT companies, NetBeans Or Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, ide

I'm new to Java. I took an introductory course where I was using NetBeans, but I noticed that some of my classmates were using Eclipse. From what I've understood, Eclipse is the popular IDE among IT companies.
My question is, as a new programmer, should I stay with NetBeans or switch to Eclipse?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. Most places will let you choose your own IDE, but working with a new should be pretty trivial. Just use whatever tools you like best. Everyone once in while try some thing new to see it might be better.

Comment: @Mason240: Really? Most places will let me choose? I thought every company has its own rules about those things.

Comment: @wizardo: I've never heard of a company that *required* developers to use a particular IDE or editor. What's far more common is that a given tool has majority use among members of a team, esp senior members, and it becomes the de facto standard because if you use Tool X, you're most likely to get help faster, leverage what others have done, etc.

Comment: @ckhan: Ok, so I guess I should stick with NetBeans for now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You forgot one more: IntelliJ.

They are all different and there is no single "best one", for example each has a feature that another doesn't.

My personal remarks:

- Eclipse is probably the most *open*. It's very actively developed. It was the de facto standard at all 4 companies I worked for so far. Eclipse is completely free.
- IntelliJ is kind of *intelligent*. It's really interesting to use, but not all features are available in the community edition. I evaluated it because somebody claimed that a study shows that it makes you about 10% more productive but I haven't seen the study itself. I think IntelliJ is awesome but I'm so used to Eclipse it's really hard to switch.
- Unfortunately I've never even seen NetBeans.

Considering these points, Eclipse *seems* the safest choice, due to its popularity at my past workplaces and open and free nature. But your mileage may vary.

Just keep in mind that Eclipse/NetBeans/IntelliJ whatever are just tools. It doesn't matter whichever you choose, the most important thing is that you get coding, and code well. Use whichever makes you the most productive.

Comment: thanks, very constructive answer.

Comment: _Just keep in mind that Eclipse/NetBeans/IntelliJ whatever are just tools. It doesn't matter whichever you choose, the most important thing is that you get coding, and code well._ Best advice I could get in this point.

Comment: So you want to be a GREAT coder. That's good news! Then you will love this book by Jeff Atwood: http://www.hyperink.com/Effective-Programming-More-Than-Writing-Code-b1559

Comment: Thanks! It looks like the free excerpts include the entire book...

Comment: I agree with the conclusion, but you cannot recommend Eclipse over NetBeans if you never even seen NetBeans!

Comment: @Jaec you're right. I updated my answer. In any case, this is not a good question+answer on Stack Overflow because it's inevitably opinion-based. The last paragraph in my post is the most important.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I think both are equally prevalent.  Once you learn one, it is not a huge deal to switch to the other.  Those with whom I work have their own preferences, and the company does not have a preference - nor do the contracting companies that we work with.  To each his own seems to be pretty standard policy.  That being said, in my experience the IDE choice has sometimes been defined by the problem at hand (ease of use, different plugins for particular purposes, etc.).

Bottom line - learn both.  It isn't that hard to do and you will probably use both eventually anyway.